# Find partial name matches between two columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
Column A

Camisi, Terry
Goodman, Harris
Kostin, Heidi
Malachi, Lorrie

Column B

Terry
Harris
Lorri
Heidi
```

I'd like to create a formula that looks for a partial match of a name in two columns (Column A and Column B) in the same sheet, and if there is a partial match between the two names, it returns the value of Column B in Column C. Pls note, names are not in sequence.

@Harun24HR, Please see modified question below:

Column A (Last Name, First Name)

```
Camisi, Terry
Goodman, Harris
Kostin, Heidi
Malachi, Lorrie
```

Column B (Last Name)

```
Goodman
Malachi
Kostin
Camisi
```

Column C (First Name)

```
Harris
Lorri
Heidi
Terry
```

I have three columns, I need to compare Column A vs. Column B & C to find a partial match. If there's a match Name from Column A should be visible in Column D. Please advise. Thx

Comment: What have you tried? Post your code/formula into your question.

Comment: Would "Lorri" and "Lorrie" be considered a match? Would be significantly easier if not

Comment: @eulers disgraced stepchild: Let's go with the assumption that it's not.

Comment: @DamalRaval Same formula should work, just need to change `INDEX()` array. `=INDEX($A$1:$A$4,MATCH("*"&B1&"*",$A$1:$A$4,0))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `MATCH()` function with wildcard matching.

```
=INDEX($B$1:$B$4,MATCH("*"&B1&"*",$A$1:$A$4,0))
```

Or below one

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH("*"&B1&"*",$A$1:$A$4,0)),B1,"")
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! This is working for me! Can I ask something more on this same?

Comment: Glad to know. You can ask but if you found it working then please consider accepting the answer (tick mark the answer) first.

Comment: Full Name Last Name First Name
Kostin, Heidi Fitzgerald Craig
Malachi, Lorrie Kostin Heidi
Buck, Alicia Buck Alicia
Goodman, Harris Camisi Terry
Fitzgerald, Craig Goodman Harris
Camisi, Terry Malachi Lorrie

Here in Column A, I have Full Name (Last Name, First Name), in Column B I have "Last Name" and in Column C, I have "First Name". Can you help me find the matches? Answer should be visible in Column D. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: @DamalRaval Please add data to your post. Can not read comment as it is showing in one line.